# How does this ThreadLocal prevent the Classloader from getting GCed

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand how `Threadlocal` can cause `Classloader` leak. So for this I have this code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        loadClass();
        while (true) {
            System.gc();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static void loadClass() throws Exception {
        URL url = Main.class.getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation();
        MyCustomClassLoader cl = new MyCustomClassLoader(url);
        Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("com.test.Foo");
        clazz.newInstance();
        cl = null;
    }
}

class MyCustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    public MyCustomClassLoader(URL... urls) {
        super(urls, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("*** CustomClassLoader finalized!");
    }
}
```

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Bar> tl = new ThreadLocal<Bar>();

    public Foo() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        tl.set(bar);
        System.out.println("Test ClassLoader: " + this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println(this + " finalized!");
    }
}
```

Bar.java

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar() {
        System.out.println(this + " created");
        System.out.println("Bar ClassLoader: " + this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println(this + " finalized");
    }
}
```

After running this code it shows that `MyCustomClassloader`  and `Bar` finalize is not called, only `Foo` finalize is called.
But when I change Threadlocal to String then all the finalize is called.

```
public class Foo {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> tl = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public Foo() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        tl.set("some");
        System.out.println("Test ClassLoader: " + this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader());
    }
```

Can you please explain why there is a difference when using ThreadLocal as `String` vs `Bar`?

Comment: Why would it be finalized if you store it in the ThreadLocal? You've stored it somewhere that is still reachable (because `Foo` is still loaded). If you store a string in the ThreadLocal, you're not storing the Bar, so it is unreachable and can be gc'd.

Comment: It’s not as simple as it looks on the first glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the thread local variable to an instance of `Bar`, the value has an implicit reference to its defining class loader, which is also the defining class loader of `Foo` and hence, has an implicit reference to its `static` variable `tl` holding the `ThreadLocal`.

In contrast, the `String` class is defined by the bootstrap loader and has no implicit reference to the the `Foo` class.

Now, a reference cycle is not preventing garbage collection per se. If only one object holds a reference to a member of the cycle and that object becomes unreachable, the entire cycle would become unreachable. The problem here is that the object still referencing the cycle is the `Thread` that is still alive.

The specific value is associated with the combination of a `ThreadLocal` instance and a `Thread` instance and we’d wish that if *either* of them becomes unreachable, it would stop referencing the value. Unfortunately, no such feature exists. We can only associate a value with the reachability of one object, like with the key of a `WeakHashMap`, but not of two.

In the OpenJDK implementation, the `Thread` is the owner of this construct, which makes it immune against values back-referencing the `Thread`. E.g.

```java
ThreadLocal<Thread> local = new ThreadLocal<>();

ReferenceQueue<Thread> q = new ReferenceQueue<>();

Set<Reference<?>> refs = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

new Thread(() -> {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    local.set(t);
    refs.add(new WeakReference<>(t, q));
}).start();

Reference<?> r;
while((r = q.remove(2000)) == null) {
    System.gc();
}

if(refs.remove(r)) System.out.println("Collected");
else System.out.println("Something very suspicuous is going on");
```

This will print `Collected`, indicating that the reference from the value to the `Thread` did not prevent the removal, unlike `put(t, t)` on a `WeakHashMap`.

The price is that this construct is not immune against backreferences to the `ThreadLocal` instance.

```java
ReferenceQueue<Object> q = new ReferenceQueue<>();

Set<Reference<?>> refs = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

createThreadLocal(refs, q);

Reference<?> r;
while((r = q.remove(2000)) == null) {
    System.gc();
}

if(refs.remove(r)) System.out.println("Collected");
else System.out.println("Something very suspicuous is going on");
```

```java
static void createThreadLocal(Set<Reference<?>> refs, ReferenceQueue<Object> q) {
    ThreadLocal<ThreadLocal<?>> local = new ThreadLocal<>();
    local.set(local);
    refs.add(new WeakReference<>(local, q));
}
```

This will hang forever, as the backreference from the `ThreadLocal` to itself prevents its garbage collection, as long as the associated thread is still alive.

Your case is just a special variant of it, as the backreference is through the `Bar` instance, its defining loader, to `Foo`’s `static` variable. But the principle is the same.

You only need to change the line

```java
loadClass();
```

to

```java
new Thread(new FutureTask(() -> { loadClass(); return null; })).start();
```

to stop the value from being associated with the main thread. Then, the class loader and all associated classes and instances get garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for the details, could you please explain "to stop the value from being associated with the main thread", is this because New Thread does not have a reference on Main thread?

Comment: You are setting a value on a *thread local* variable. The value will be associated with the thread executing the `tl.set(bar);` statement. When the main thread executes the statement, the value is associated with the main thread which is still alive afterwards (as it is the thread calling `System.gc()` in a loop). When a different thread executes the statement, the value will be associated with that particular thread and can be removed when that thread terminates.