# How to free all resources after reading a JRT?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I am trying to read the list of modules available in a given Java 9+ installation, given its Java Home, using the method described in [How to extract the file jre-9/lib/modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46451977/2466911).

The solution works, but it appears that the resources allocated to read the content of the Java Runtime Image are never freed, causing a memory leak, observable with VisualVM for instance:

[image: Memory leak as observed with VisualVM]

How can I fix the memory leak in the following reproduction?

```java
package leak;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class JrtfsLeak {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path javaHome = Paths.get(args[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
      modules(javaHome).close();
    }
  }

  private static Stream<Path> modules(Path javaHome) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> env = Collections.singletonMap("java.home", javaHome.toString());
    Path jrtfsJar = javaHome.resolve("lib").resolve("jrt-fs.jar");
    try (URLClassLoader classloader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jrtfsJar.toUri().toURL() })) {
      try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"), env, classloader)) {
        Path modulesRoot = fs.getPath("modules");
        return Files.list(modulesRoot);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Java version(s) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jabba to manage my Java installations. I used with the following versions: adopt@1.14.0-2, adopt@1.11.0-7, adopt@1.8.0-242

Comment: Good observation! This seems like a real JDK bug caused by the careless use of thread locals in `ImageBufferCache`

Comment: @apangin just came to [the same conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68083960/2711488)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that when you are running under Java 9 or newer, the underlying implementation will create a new class loader for the `jrt-fs.jar` when you specify the `java.home` option. So, these classes are not loaded by your `URLClassLoader` but a different class loader. When you don’t need support for versions prior to 9, you can omit the creation of a class loader.

In either case, they’re loaded by a custom class loader and could be unloaded when the garbage collector supports it. But the class `jdk.internal.jimage.ImageBufferCache` contains:

```java
private static final ThreadLocal<BufferReference[]> CACHE =
    new ThreadLocal<BufferReference[]>() {
        @Override
        protected BufferReference[] initialValue() {
            // 1 extra slot to simplify logic of releaseBuffer()
            return new BufferReference[MAX_CACHED_BUFFERS + 1];
        }
    };
```

As explained in [How does this ThreadLocal prevent the Classloader from getting GCed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66458166/2711488), a backreference from the value to the thread local can prevent its garbage collection and when the thread local is stored in a `static` variable, a reference to one of the classes loaded by the same class loader is enough.

And here, the value is an array of `BufferReference`, which means even when all entries of that array have been cleared, the array type itself has an implicit reference to the class loader of that filesystem.

But since its a thread local variable, we can work-around it by letting the key thread die. When I change your code to

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Path javaHome = Paths.get(args[0]);
    Runnable r = () -> test(javaHome);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
    }
}

static void test(Path javaHome) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        try(var s = modules(javaHome)) {}
        catch(IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

the classes get unloaded.

Answer (score 6):

This is a JDK bug [JDK-8260621](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8260621) that has been fixed in JDK 17.
It was caused by a careless use of thread locals in `ImageBufferCache`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to *javadoc* for method [list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)) (in class `java.nio.file.Files`). Here is the relevant part.

> **API Note:**
> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directory is closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.

In other words you need to close the `Stream` returned by your `modules` method.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, this is a mistake I made while minimizing the reproduction. I updated the question to close the stream, but this doesn't fix the problem, unfortunately: the leak is still there.